# xml to listview calculate

Tags: android, xml, listview

**prc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="productlar">
        <item>product1</item>
        <item>product2</item>
        <item>product3</item>
        <item>product4</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="prices">
        <item>43.99</item>
        <item>42.66</item>
        <item>41.61</item>
        <item>40.47</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I'm trying to find the code for a few nights but did not get a result. I can transfer to prices `prc.xml` to `listview` with following code. But this code only conveys the same products to `listview`.

```
 ListView fiyatlistele=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
 String[] arrayim=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.prc);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
         (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayim);
 fiyatlistele.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have to calculate the product final price before transfer to listview. 
Example: all products prices(in xml) must be multiplied by 2 then transfer to listview. (It will change the final price according to the customer)

Comment: so you simply want to multiply every item of your arrayim[] by some number say 2 and then set that new array to your listview adapter right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this, a simple multiplication with 2 for all the array elements. Of course you array is in string format so you will have to parse the values to `Double` before multiplying it with 2.

```
ListView fiyatlistele=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
String[] arrayim=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.prices);
for(int i = 0; i < arrayim.length; i++)
{
    arrayim[i] = ((Double.parseDouble(arrayim[i]) * 2) + "";
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
     (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayim);
fiyatlistele.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i tried to your suggestion but didnt work. 
Said that: Operator * cannot be Aplied to java.lang.String, int
arrayim[i] = arrayim[i] * 2; (this line)

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't notice that. I though it was an integer array. Please try now.

Comment: Generally result will be double so i have to doublearray isnt it? how can i turn from String to Double?

Comment: Android doesn't support double array.

Comment: So what is your advice?

Comment: You could use a typed array for another solution I guess.

Comment: Or you could multiply the values in your xml with 100 and make it as a integer array. While calculation you multiply the value by 2 and then divide by 100. You can use any way which suits you.

Comment: Finaly i found:
arrayim[i] = String.valueOf((Double.valueOf(arrayim[i]) * 2));
thanx for your interest

Comment: Technically its same as what I have suggested in my code.

Comment: Also please don't forget to select it as answer if it helped. :)

Comment: By the way last question about that. How can i set 2 digit after decimal point in array and listview?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < fiyat.length; i++)
        {

            fiyat[i] = String.valueOf((Double.valueOf(fiyat[i]) * Double.valueOf(tvisktopl.getText().toString())));

            lvyemfiyat.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fiyat));

        }